# filter for intents / sender of the Intent, android

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

How do i know the sender of an Intent?

This is the intent filter i have.

```
<intent-filter>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
      <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

So right now if i click on an item in dropbox and click "share", my activity will appear in the list. However, i want my app to ONLY appear in dropbox share list but not others..

I guess the question here is, is there any other filter i can add to only filter for dropbox? Or is there anything unique within the dropbox intent for now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, i want my app to ONLY appear in dropbox share list but not others.

That is not supported. You are welcome to write your own DropBox client using their API, with your particular functionality as part of that app.

> I guess the question here is, is there any other filter i can add to only filter for dropbox?

I doubt it. DropBox is most likely simply using `ACTION_SEND` with the proper MIME type, as that is what is best for DropBox and the users of DropBox.

> Or is there anything unique within the dropbox intent for now?

You would have to ask DropBox that question. Bear in mind that they may change this over time. And, even if there is something, most likely you will not be able to filter on that, so you will still show up in the chooser for other applications.